# ROR if statement against current URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am sure this is really simple so apologies for the naive question.

I am trying to test if my current page is `'jobs#index'`. If it is I have some additional CSS and content that I would to include in the page, if not then I would like it to load the page without this additional content.

I believe it should be something along these lines but I can't seem to get it right.

```
 <% if path == 'jobs#index' %>
  <div class="slidingDiv">
    Fill this space with really interesting content. 
  </div>
  <div class="show_hide">
    FILTERS
  </div>
 <% else %>
 <% end %>
```

Any advice really would be much appreciated!

Comment: try `request.path == jobs_path`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% if params[:action] == "index" && params[:controller] == "jobs" %>
```

I would put that in a helper method though.

Comment: this solution works but is not elegant nor really maintainable

Comment: Can you explain? I would set up a helper and in it list the action and controllers I wanted to show the code. What would be a better solution? Cheers

Comment: I always rely on path names. Submitted a solution in comment above

Answer (score 6):

There is built-in [`current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F#method-i-current_page-3F) method in rails.

```
if current_page?(:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index')
```

Additionally you can do:

```
if controller_name == 'jobs' && action_name == 'index'
```

Btw, you can drop `<% else %>` in your example code above.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a helper method like below. You can pass more paths this way.

in view

```
<% if is_path?("/hello/world", root_path) %>
```

in helper

```
def is_path?(*paths)
  paths.include?(request.path)
end
```

note: Try to use named helpers for routes

> jobs#index equals to jobs_path